# Migrating Wordpress Site Serialized Data

Tags: wordpress, serialization, widget, advanced-custom-fields

Hi I am having issues migrating a wordpress site:

I am using INTERCONNECT/IT SAFE SEARCH AND REPLACE ON DATABASE WITH SERIALIZED DATA V3.1.0 as there is some serialized data such as:

- All Page Templates are resetting to default (I have some ACF Fields not showing properly)
- Widgets
- Max Mega Menu Plugin reseting to default.

I have used this tool before without a hitch but some reason it is not working this time.

Not sure what it could be? Anyone else have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Used https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ plugin

Comment: Use https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

Comment: Both are paid plugins to handle serialised data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the INTERCONNECT/IT SAFE SEARCH AND REPLACE ON DATABASE WITH SERIALIZED DATA V3.1.0 working again properly, was do with wordpress versions - re-installed a later version of WP and worked.